# HTML 5 video and audio appended to a SourceBuffer become de-synchronised

Tags: javascript, socket.io, synchronization, streaming, media-source

I'm using the Media Source Extensions API to capture the desktop / an application / a chrome tab with it's audio and stream that data to multiple clients through Socket.io.

I am using a MediaRecorder which routinely records the stream every 10 ms, sending each 10ms chunk to my server which relays it back to every client to be appended to a SourceBuffer which is attached to a MediaSource attached to a video tag. Both the audio and video are successfully sent, received and displayed by the video tag, however, after a short time the audio gets ahead of the video and both gradually get further apart.

```
let videoMimeType = 'video/webm;codecs="vp9,opus"';
let player = document.getElementById("player");
let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
    if (videoBuffer == null) {
      videoBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(videoMimeType);
      videoBuffer.mode = 'sequence'
    }
});

navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
      video: {
        width: {
          max: 1280
        },
        height: {
          max: 720
        },
        frameRate: 30
      },
      audio: {
        echoCancellation: false,
        googEchoCancellation: false,
        googAutoGainControl: false,
        googAutoGainControl2: false,
        googNoiseSuppression: false,
        googHighpassFilter: false
      }
    }).then(
      stream => {
        let videoRecorder = new MediaRecorder(new MediaStream(stream), {
          mimeType: videoMimeType
        });

        stream.getTracks()[0].addEventListener("ended", () => {
          stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
          videoRecorder.stop();
          playing = false;
          player.src = "";
          socket.emit("end")
          return;
        });

        videoRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
          if (e.data.size > 0) {
            socket.emit('update', e.data);
          }
        };

        videoRecorder.start(10);

      },
      error => {
        console.log("Unable to acquire screen capture", error);
      });

socket.on("update", (arrayBuffer) => {
  if (playing) {
    player.play()
    if (!videoBuffer.updating && queue.length == 0) {
      videoBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
    }
  }
})
```

I expected the video and audio to remain synchronised throughout playback but instead over time the audio get ahead of the video. The video also buffers at times, which seems to herald the de-synchronisation, though during buffering both the audio and video stop and then start again after.

Comment: i'm also doing the same and stuck now,do you find any solution ?